# SQL group by with NULL

Tags: sql, null

I have a table something like this:

```
ID   ProductID   ProductName  Price
==   =========   ===========  =====
1    XX1           TShirt      10
2    XX1           TShirt      10
3    NULL          TShirt      10
4    XX2           Shirt       20
5    XX3           Shirt1      30
```

Now I want this to group by `ProductName` and results will be as follows

```
ID   ProductID   ProductName  Price
==   =========   ===========  =====
1    XX1           TShirt      30
4    XX2           Shirt       20
5    XX3           Shirt1      30
```

Thanks

Comment: have you actually tried anything or expecting us to do it for you?

Comment: You would also need to specify what ID you want in your output when you group these.  Doesn't make sense.  You may also want to specify which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: What is the purpose of the .net tag here? You really need to explain more...

Comment: Why should NULL be counted as XX1?   What if there was another "TShirt" with a different size?

Comment: Why should `NULL`/`TShirt` be counted the same as `XX1` / `TShirt` ? What is the logic behind that? What would happen if there was also `XX4` / `TShirt`? And why?

Answer (score 5):

`ProductID` seems to be irrelevant for the group, so don't use it. To get all columns you could use a CTE and a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT ID,   
          ProductID,   
          ProductName,  
          Price = SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName),
          RN = ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName ORDER BY ID)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT CTE.* FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

If you want to take the row which contains the `ProductID`(where it is not `NULL`) modify the `ORDER BY`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT ID,   
          ProductID,   
          ProductName,  
          Price = SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName),
          RN = ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName 
                                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                                     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ID)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT CTE.* FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Very good, so you get my vote. However, I suspect the OP doesn't really know what they want and probably doesn't need anything more complex than grouping by `ProductName` and summing the price (i.e. no ID required)

Comment: In the same way that `ProductID` seems irrelevant, I'd say that `ID` is irrelevant too; frankly, if we are to drop `ProductId`, I can't think that this needs anything more complex than just `select ProductName, SUM(Price) as [TotalPrice] from TableName group by ProductName`

Comment: @MarcGravell: maybe he wants all fields even if they are irrelevant, if only for "debugging" purposes. But it's important to know which columns have to be used for the `GROUP BY` and which rows of the groups should be returned. The sample data suggests that he want the rows with data.

Comment: @Tim yep; and your query does that beautifully; personally I'd have gone with `SELECT ID, ProductID, ProductName, Price FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 ORDER BY ID` for the last line, but it works ;p